# How to add text on the background Image

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

I want to add some text on the background image in my ionic mobile. I have used this sample of code for add background image.

```
<ion-content >
    <div  class="hero slide-up" style="background-image: url('img/vegi.jpg');">    
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write text inside the `div`... if you want more control over the text you could wrap it inside a `p` or `span` tag then position it to your liking.

```
<ion-content >
        <div  class="hero slide-up" style="background-image: url('img/vegi.jpg');">
             <span>my text goes here</span>
        </div>
</ion-content>
```